# Most efficient way to create a comparative table with Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

using Excel (mostly the VBA part), I would like to do the following:

I have two different tables with different kind of data, but they both have at least the 4 following columns in common:

- the name of the employee
- the name of the project he worked on
- the day he worked on it
- the number of hour in that day that he worked on it.

One of the table represents the planified working time (by instance this employee should work x hours on project A and y hours on project B on the 5th of May...) and the other table represents the actual working time, i. e. the time the employee actually spent working on a project.

The actual project on which the employee worked on may differ from what was planified, or it may be the same but he might have spent a different amount of time on it.

Being new to Excel I was wondering if any of you could give me ideas on the most efficient way to do this.  Since I have a lot of rows, I'm a bit reticent at the idea of using too many loops.

Thank you!

Comment: Share an example data of both tables. What is it exactly you want to calculate? You just mentioned the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are structured tables (let us say their worksheet names being `Planned` and `Actual`) in Excel I would **create a MS Query** like this:

```
SELECT Plan.Employee, Plan.Project, SUM(Plan.PlannedHrs), SUM(Act.ActualHrs),SUM(Act.ActualHrs) / SUM(Plan.PlannedHrs)
FROM [Planned$] as Plan 
INNER JOIN [Actual$] as Act 
ON Plan.Project = Act.Project AND Plan.Employee=Act.Employee
GROUP BY Plan.Employee, Plan.project, Act.Project, Act.Employee
```

**The above query will compare hrs per project (Planned vs Actual). This is just an example as you can calculate other metrics.**

Using MS Queries?: `Data->From Other Sources->From Microsoft Query`
or use my SQL AddIn (just to create the query): http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/